# If has $title in widgets

Tags: php, widgets

I'm writing a widget to display 125 x 125 pixel ads. There are 6 spaces for the ads and currently all works.

However, I would to add some conditional logic so that if nothing is entered in the values in the widget admin for an ad, then no add is shown.

I think this can be done by using PHP if or something, I can't remember what it is exactly. I need it with the `<?php & ?>` tags on. It needs to check if `$adone` exists and if not display an empty space.

I know this code here is wrong but something like this:

```
<?php if_has($adone_img)  ?>
/** Ad 1 code here */
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**The widget class:**

```
<?php
/**
 * square_ad Class
 */
class square_ad extends WP_Widget {
    /** constructor */
    function square_ad() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'square_ad', 'description' => 'Up to 6 125px by 125px ads for your sidebar.');
        $control_ops = array('id_base' => 'square_ad');
        $this->WP_Widget('square_ad', 'SILVERLINE 125 Ad', $widget_ops, $control_ops);  
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::widget */
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        $adone_img = apply_filters( 'adone', $instance['adone_img'] );
        $adone_link = apply_filters( 'adone', $instance['adone_link'] );

        $adtwo_img = apply_filters( 'adtwo', $instance['adtwo_img'] );
        $adtwo_link = apply_filters( 'adtwo', $instance['adtwo_link'] );    

        $adthree_img = apply_filters( 'adthree', $instance['adthree_img'] );
        $adthree_link = apply_filters( 'adthree', $instance['adthree_link'] );

        $adfour_img = apply_filters( 'adfour', $instance['adfour_img'] );
        $adfour_link = apply_filters( 'adfour', $instance['adfour_link'] );

        $adfive_img = apply_filters( 'adfive', $instance['adfive_img'] );
        $adfive_link = apply_filters( 'adfive', $instance['adfive_link'] );

        $adsix_img = apply_filters( 'adsix', $instance['adsix_img'] );
        $adsix_link = apply_filters( 'adsix', $instance['adsix_link'] );

        echo('<h3 style="margin-left:5px; margin-top:-30px;" class="widget-title-text">');
        echo($title);
        echo('</h3>');
        echo('<div id="widget-container-125">');
 ?>



<a href="<?php echo ($adone_link);?>"><img class="box-container" src="<?php echo ($adone_img);?>" width="125" height="125" /></a>
<a href="<?php echo ($adtwo_link);?>"><img align="right" class="box-container" src="<?php echo ($adtwo_img);?>"  width="125" height="125" /><br/></a>
<a href="<?php echo ($adthree_link);?>"><img class="box-container" src="<?php echo ($adthree_img);?>" width="125" height="125" /></a>
<a href="<?php echo ($adfour_link);?>"><img align="right" class="box-container" src="<?php echo ($adfour_img);?>"  width="125" height="125" /><br/></a>
<a href="<?php echo ($adfive_link);?>"><img class="box-container" src="<?php echo ($adfive_img);?>" width="125" height="125" /></a>
<a href="<?php echo ($adsix_link);?>"><img class="box-container" src="<?php echo ($adsix_img);?>" width="125" height="125" /></a>

<style type="text/css">
</style>
<br/><br/></div>

        <?php 
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::update */
    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);

        $instance['adone_img'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adone_img']);
        $instance['adone_link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adone_link']);

        $instance['adtwo_img'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adtwo_img']);
        $instance['adtwo_link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adtwo_link']);

        $instance['adthree_img'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adthree_img']);
        $instance['adthree_link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adthree_link']);

        $instance['adfour_img'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adfour_img']);
        $instance['adfour_link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adfour_link']);

        $instance['adfive_img'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adfive_img']);
        $instance['adfive_link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adfive_link']);

        $instance['adsix_img'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adsix_img']);
        $instance['adsix_link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['adsix_link']);
        return $instance;
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::form */
    function form( $instance ) {
        if ( $instance ) {
            $title = esc_attr( $instance[ 'title' ] );
            $adone_img = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adone_img' ] );
            $adone_link = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adone_link' ] );

            $adtwo_img = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adtwo_img' ] );
            $adtwo_link = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adtwo_link' ] );

            $adthree_img = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adthree_img' ] );
            $adthree_link = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adthree_link' ] );

            $adfour_img = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adfour_img' ] );
            $adfour_link = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adfour_link' ] );

            $adfive_img = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adfive_img' ] );
            $adfive_link = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adfive_link' ] );

            $adsix_img = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adsix_img' ] );
            $adsix_link = esc_attr( $instance[ 'adsix_link' ] );
        }
        else {
            $title = __( '', 'text_domain' );
        }
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />


        <h4>Ad One</h4>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adone_img'); ?>"><?php _e('Image URL:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adone_img'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adone_img'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adone_img; ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adone_link'); ?>"><?php _e('AD Link:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adone_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adone_link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adone_link; ?>" />

        <h4>Ad Two</h4>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adtwo_img'); ?>"><?php _e('Image URL:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adtwo_img'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adtwo_img'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adtwo_img; ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adtwo_link'); ?>"><?php _e('AD Link:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adtwo_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adtwo_link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adtwo_link; ?>" />

        <h4>Ad Three</h4>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adthree_img'); ?>"><?php _e('Image URL:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adthree_img'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adthree_img'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adthree_img; ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adthree_link'); ?>"><?php _e('AD Link:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adthree_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adthree_link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adthree_link; ?>" />

        <h4>Ad Four</h4>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adfour_img'); ?>"><?php _e('Image URL:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adfour_img'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adfour_img'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adfour_img; ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adfour_link'); ?>"><?php _e('AD Link:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adfour_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adfour_link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adfour_link; ?>" />

        <h4>Ad Five</h4>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adfive_img'); ?>"><?php _e('Image URL:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adfive_img'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adfive_img'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adfive_img; ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adfive_link'); ?>"><?php _e('AD Link:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adfive_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adfive_link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adfive_link; ?>" />

        <h4>Ad Six</h4>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adsix_img'); ?>"><?php _e('Image URL::'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adsix_img'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adsix_img'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adsix_img; ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adsix_link'); ?>"><?php _e('AD Link:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adsix_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adsix_link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $adsix_link; ?>" />
                </p>
        <?php 
    }

} // class square_ad

// register square_ad widget
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'return register_widget("square_ad");' ) );
```

Comment: Include your complete widget class. There is no other to see the best direction.

Comment: I copied your code from the text file into the question(where it should have been to begin with). You can always remove it later by editing the question if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be possible like this:

```
<?php
    /** @see WP_Widget::widget */
        function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            extract( $args );
            $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
            # >>>> NEW
            if ( ! isset( $title ) OR empty( $title ) );
                return;
            # <<<< NEW
            echo $before_widget;
            if ( $title )
                echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; 
            ?>
            Hello, World!
            <?php 
            echo $after_widget;
        }
?>
```

Comment: Yeah sort of but I'm not trying to do it with the title, and It doesn't really fit in with the code. Nor can I get it to work.. Here is the code for the widget: http://magicapple.co.uk/code.txt On line 49 is where the code for the actual widget is. And I'm not using $before_widget or $after_widget either.. I could see it working using the format I showed in my question..

Comment: And where's the problem replacing `$title` with something custom from your code?

Comment: Because I'm not entirely sure how to include that snippet into my code. And when I take out the bits I don't need I get I server error, I know I'm doing something wrong, but thats what I'm asking..

Comment: Ok. First: You're doing something that's _waaay_ beyond your skills, so stick with the comments: `NEW` enclosures the important part that checks if the attribute is set and `return` aborts it, if not present. The `extract` part, well... extracts your input arguments into stand alone variables. Then you can access `'title' => 'Some Title'` as `$title`. The same way you can access every other input argument. Btw: You'd loose much less time if you'd sit down and try to study the basics of php for 2 hours...

Comment: Maybe so, but I am learning. I understand what most of the code does, I just have trouble changing it. I did however just try out this code: <?php if ( $adone_img ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?> which displays the title when there is a value in $adone_img and It works, I just need it to echo this code instead of the title: <a href="<?php echo ($adone_link);?>"><img class="box-container" src="<?php echo ($adone_img);?>" width="125" height="125" /></a> I realize you can't put PHP in PHP so I need to work out how to make that work..

Comment: Okay, I've worked it out. And It works. Here is the final code I used:   <?php if ( $adone_img ) echo '<a href="'.$adone_link.'"><img class="box-container" src="'.$adone_img.'" width="125" height="125" /></a>'; ?>     Thanks for your help!

Comment: @iJamesPine There's a check mark under the vote score for the answer. Please mark it, so it doesn't stay _open_. Btw: You need to check if it's set too. Not only if it contains something that returns `true`...